# BIG QUERY - can't find file

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to pull data from several tables. Big Q won't pull all the data from my files. it will only pull from 2023-01. I tried to loop the tables but there was an external problem. I tried to find out if other tables were having issues and 2023-02 won't pull because it says it can't find the info.

WITH all_data AS (
SELECT
LOWER(TRIM(member_casual)) AS cleaned_member_casual,
COALESCE(ride_id, 'Missing Ride ID') AS ride_id,
COALESCE(start_lng, 0) AS start_lng,
COALESCE(start_lat, 0) AS start_lat,
COALESCE(end_lng, 0) AS end_lng,
COALESCE(end_lat, 0) AS end_lat,
'2023-01' AS table_name
FROM
`kane-415618.Cyclistic.2023-01`

UNION ALL
SELECT
LOWER(TRIM(member_casual)) AS cleaned_member_casual,
COALESCE(ride_id, 'Missing Ride ID') AS ride_id,
COALESCE(start_lng, 0) AS start_lng,
COALESCE(start_lat, 0) AS start_lat,
COALESCE(end_lng, 0) AS end_lng,
COALESCE(end_lat, 0) AS end_lat,
'2023-02' AS table_name
FROM
`kane-415618.Cyclistic.2023-02`

UNION ALL
SELECT
LOWER(TRIM(member_casual)) AS cleaned_member_casual,
COALESCE(ride_id, 'Missing Ride ID') AS ride_id,
COALESCE(start_lng, 0) AS start_lng,
COALESCE(start_lat, 0) AS start_lat,
COALESCE(end_lng, 0) AS end_lng,
COALESCE(end_lat, 0) AS end_lat,
'2023-03' AS table_name
FROM
`kane-415618.Cyclistic.2023-03`

UNION ALL
SELECT
LOWER(TRIM(member_casual)) AS cleaned_member_casual,
COALESCE(ride_id, 'Missing Ride ID') AS ride_id,
COALESCE(start_lng, 0) AS start_lng,
COALESCE(start_lat, 0) AS start_lat,
COALESCE(end_lng, 0) AS end_lng,
COALESCE(end_lat, 0) AS end_lat,
'2023-04' AS table_name
FROM
`kane-415618.Cyclistic.2023-04`

UNION ALL
SELECT
LOWER(TRIM(member_casual)) AS cleaned_member_casual,
COALESCE(ride_id, 'Missing Ride ID') AS ride_id,
COALESCE(start_lng, 0) AS start_lng,
COALESCE(start_lat, 0) AS start_lat,
COALESCE(end_lng, 0) AS end_lng,
COALESCE(end_lat, 0) AS end_lat,
'2023-05' AS table_name
FROM
`kane-415618.Cyclistic.2023-05`

UNION ALL
SELECT
LOWER(TRIM(member_casual)) AS cleaned_member_casual,
COALESCE(ride_id, 'Missing Ride ID') AS ride_id,
COALESCE(start_lng, 0) AS start_lng,
COALESCE(start_lat, 0) AS start_lat,
COALESCE(end_lng, 0) AS end_lng,
COALESCE(end_lat, 0) AS end_lat,
'2023-06' AS table_name
FROM
`kane-415618.Cyclistic.2023-06`

UNION ALL
SELECT
LOWER(TRIM(member_casual)) AS cleaned_member_casual,
COALESCE(ride_id, 'Missing Ride ID') AS ride_id,
COALESCE(start_lng, 0) AS start_lng,
COALESCE(start_lat, 0) AS start_lat,
COALESCE(end_lng, 0) AS end_lng,
COALESCE(end_lat, 0) AS end_lat,
'2023-07' AS table_name
FROM
`kane-415618.Cyclistic.2023-07`

UNION ALL
SELECT
LOWER(TRIM(member_casual)) AS cleaned_member_casual,
COALESCE(ride_id, 'Missing Ride ID') AS ride_id,
COALESCE(start_lng, 0) AS start_lng,
COALESCE(start_lat, 0) AS start_lat,
COALESCE(end_lng, 0) AS end_lng,
COALESCE(end_lat, 0) AS end_lat,
'2023-08' AS table_name
FROM
`kane-415618.Cyclistic.2023-08`

UNION ALL
SELECT
LOWER(TRIM(member_casual)) AS cleaned_member_casual,
COALESCE(ride_id, 'Missing Ride ID') AS ride_id,
COALESCE(start_lng, 0) AS start_lng,
COALESCE(start_lat, 0) AS start_lat,
COALESCE(end_lng, 0) AS end_lng,
COALESCE(end_lat, 0) AS end_lat,
'2023-09' AS table_name
FROM
`kane-415618.Cyclistic.2023-09`

UNION ALL
SELECT
LOWER(TRIM(member_casual)) AS cleaned_member_casual,
COALESCE(ride_id, 'Missing Ride ID') AS ride_id,
COALESCE(start_lng, 0) AS start_lng,
COALESCE(start_lat, 0) AS start_lat,
COALESCE(end_lng, 0) AS end_lng,
COALESCE(end_lat, 0) AS end_lat,
'2023-10' AS table_name
FROM
`kane-415618.Cyclistic.2023-10`

UNION ALL
SELECT
LOWER(TRIM(member_casual)) AS cleaned_member_casual,
COALESCE(ride_id, 'Missing Ride ID') AS ride_id,
COALESCE(start_lng, 0) AS start_lng,
COALESCE(start_lat, 0) AS start_lat,
COALESCE(end_lng, 0) AS end_lng,
COALESCE(end_lat, 0) AS end_lat,
'2023-11' AS table_name
FROM
`kane-415618.Cyclistic.2023-11`

UNION ALL
SELECT
LOWER(TRIM(member_casual)) AS cleaned_member_casual,
COALESCE(ride_id, 'Missing Ride ID') AS ride_id,
COALESCE(start_lng, 0) AS start_lng,
COALESCE(start_lat, 0) AS start_lat,
COALESCE(end_lng, 0) AS end_lng,
COALESCE(end_lat, 0) AS end_lat,
'2023-12' AS table_name
FROM
`kane-415618.Cyclistic.2023-12`

UNION ALL
SELECT
LOWER(TRIM(member_casual)) AS cleaned_member_casual,
COALESCE(ride_id, 'Missing Ride ID') AS ride_id,
COALESCE(start_lng, 0) AS start_lng,
COALESCE(start_lat, 0) AS start_lat,
COALESCE(end_lng, 0) AS end_lng,
COALESCE(end_lat, 0) AS end_lat,
'2024-01' AS table_name
FROM
`kane-415618.Cyclistic.2024-01`

UNION ALL
SELECT
LOWER(TRIM(member_casual)) AS cleaned_member_casual,
COALESCE(ride_id, 'Missing Ride ID') AS ride_id,
COALESCE(start_lng, 0) AS start_lng,
COALESCE(start_lat, 0) AS start_lat,
COALESCE(end_lng, 0) AS end_lng,
COALESCE(end_lat, 0) AS end_lat,
'2024-02' AS table_name
FROM
`kane-415618.Cyclistic.2024-02`
)

SELECT
cleaned_member_casual,
table_name,
COUNT(*) AS total_rides,
COUNT(DISTINCT ride_id) AS distinct_rides,
AVG(ST_Distance(ST_GeogPoint(start_lng, start_lat), ST_GeogPoint(end_lng, end_lat))) AS avg_distance_per_ride,
start_lat,
start_lng,
end_lat,
end_lng
FROM
all_data
GROUP BY
cleaned_member_casual,
table_name,
start_lat,
start_lng,
end_lat,
end_lng
ORDER BY
table_name,
cleaned_member_casual;
-- after pulling this data only 2023-01 was pulled

I ran this code in a separate query.

SELECT COUNT(*)

FROM `kane-415618.Cyclistic_2023_02`;
Not found: Dataset kane-415618:kane-415618 was not found in location US

when to the file and looked in details... it shows US in location. not sure why its not
finding it.

Comment: Is "kane-415618:kane-415618" the actual message?  I would have expected "kane-415618:Cyclistic".  

Also, in your sample select, you showed:

kane-415618.Cyclistic_2023_02

instead of

kane-415618.Cyclistic.2023_02